# Recursively deleting all "*.foo" files with corresponding "*.bar" files

Tags: bash, unix, recursion, zsh

How can I recursively delete all files ending in `.foo` which have a sibling file of the same name but ending in `.bar`? For example, consider the following directory tree:

```
.
├── dir
│   ├── dir
│   │   ├── file4.bar
│   │   ├── file4.foo
│   │   └── file5.foo
│   ├── file2.foo
│   ├── file3.bar
│   └── file3.foo
├── file1.bar
└── file1.foo
```

In this example `file.foo`, `file3.foo`, and `file4.foo` would be deleted since there are sibling `file{1,3,4}.bar` files. `file{2,5}.foo` should be left alone leaving this result:

```
.
├── dir
│   ├── dir
│   │   ├── file4.bar
│   │   └── file5.foo
│   ├── file2.foo
│   ├── file3.bar
└── file1.bar
```

Comment: +1 for a well illustrated question.

Comment: And thanks to `tree` for existing. :P http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember to first take a backup before you try this `find` and `rm` command.

Use this `find`:

```
find . -name "*.foo" -execdir bash -c '[[ -f "${1%.*}.bar" ]] && rm "$1"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: Nicely done! Just one note for OP, to match the performance of `xargs` one could use `+` notation to process files in parallel.

Comment: +1 I don't understand `${1%.*}` I was playing around and `${1%}` would return extension. where can I find out more about this?

Comment: @Tiago: Thanks that you can find in `man bash` Look under `Parameter Expansion` section.

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    rm -f "${FILE%.bar}".foo
done < <(exec find -type f -name '*.bar')
```

Or

```
find -type f -name '*.bar' | sed -e 's|.bar$|.foo|' | xargs rm -f
```

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` 4.0 and later, and in `zsh`:

```
shopt -s globstar   # Only needed by bash
for f in **/*.foo; do
    [[ -f ${f%.foo}.bar ]] && rm ./"$f"
done
```

In `zsh`, you can define a selective pattern that matches files ending in `.foo` only if there is a corresponding `.bar` file, so that `rm` is invoked only once, rather than once per file.

```
rm ./**/*.foo(e:'[[ -f ${REPLY%.foo}.bar ]]':)
```

Comment: Just in case, I would always use "--" before such globbed filenames, and the user may want to set GLOB_DOTS (to have a result similar to "find"): `rm -- **/*.foo(De:'[[ -f ${REPLY%.foo}.bar ]]':)`

Comment: Good points. I've edited the answer to use `./` instead of `--`, since that will work with any implementation of `rm`.