# How to compare 2 folders' permission on Unix?

Tags: unix, permissions, compare, directory

Given 2 folder: /folder1 and /folder2 and each folder has some files and subfolders inside.
I used following command to compare the file difference including sub folder :

```
diff -buf /folder1 /folder2
```

which found no difference in term of folder and file structural .

However, I found that there are some permission differences between these 2 folders' files. Is there simple way/command to compare the permission of each file under these 2 folders (including sub-folders) on Unix?

thanks,

Comment: Please edit your question (using the `{}` edit tool) and illustrate the range of possible problems. do you mean just the "folders" permissions, OR the files inside the folders OR the folders inside the folders OR the files inside the folders inside the folders? Do you know about `ls -ld folder1 folder2` ? OR `find /folder1 /folder2 -ls` ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516644/recursively-deleting-all-foo-files-with-corresponding-bar-files for some ideas on how to make your problem better specified. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to compare permissions on your two directories is to capture the output of `ls -al` to a file for each directory and `diff` those.

Say you have two directories called a and b.

```
cd a
ls -alrt > ../a.list
cd ../b
ls -alrt > ../b.list
cd ..
diff a.list b.list
```

If you find that this gives you too much noise due to file sizes and datestamps you can use awk to filter out some of the columns returned by ls e.g.:

```
ls -al | awk {'printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$9 '}
```

Or if you are lucky you might be able to remove the timestamp using:

```
ls -lh --time-style=+
```

Either way, just capture the results to two files as described above and use `diff` or `sdiff` to compare the results.

Answer (score 11):

If you have the `tree` command installed, it can do the job very simply using a similar procedure to the one that [John C suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24555304/726):

```
cd a
tree -dfpiug > ../a.list
cd ../b
tree -dfpiug > ../b.list
cd ..
diff a.list b.list
```

Or, you can just do this on one line:

```
diff <(cd a; tree -dfpiug) <(cd b; tree -dfpiug)
```

The options given to `tree` are as follows:

- `-d` only scans directories (omit to compare files as well)
- `-f` displays the full path
- `-p` displays permissions (e.g., `[drwxrwsr-x]`)
- `-i` removes `tree`'s normal hierarchical indent
- `-u` displays the owner's username
- `-g` displays the group name

Comment: May I suggest adding `-a` to `tree` to show hidden files?

Comment: Any idea how to make this one-liner work with `diff -y`? For some reason, instead of printing the diff side by side, it prints pretty much everything.

Comment: Made it into a handy function: `dirdiff () { diff <(cd $1; tree -afpiug ) <(cd $2; tree -afpiug) ;}`. Stick this into your .alias or .bashrc or whatever script runs at shell startup and then use like so: `dirdiff dir1 dir2`.

Answer (score 0):

`find /dirx/ -lsa  |awk '{ print  $6" "$6" " $11 }'`  2 times the owner
`find /dirx/ -lsa  |awk '{ print  $6" "$6" " $11 }'`  2 times the group
`find /dirx/ -lsa  |awk '{ print  $5" "$6" " $11 }'`  owner and group

Then you can redirect to a file for diff or just investigate piping to less ( or more ).
You can also pipe to grep and grep or "ungrep" (grep -v) to narrow the results.
Diff is not very useful if the dir contents are not the same